# kernel_gfx906.fatbin cycles addin missing in version 3.6 (and 3.6.1) for windows: no render support for AMD Radeon Pro VII

Tags: cycles-render-engine

In Blender version 3.5 I could use my AMD Radeon PRO VII GPU for rendering. Not so in 3.6(.1),  because `kernel_gfx906.fatbin` is missing from the `<programfolder>\blender-3.6.1-windows-x64\3.6\scripts\addons\cycles\lib` folder.

Compared to the same folder in 3.5.1 it is the only `kernel*.fatbin` file missing. The 3.5.1 `kernel_gfx906.fatbin` cannot be used in 3.6, it fully crashes the system when used in 3.6.

The error is `HIP binary kernel for this graphics card compute capabiity (9.0) not found`.

Advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

When adding tags, I found a reference to radeon prorender,  https://www.amd.com/en/technologies/radeon-prorender-downloads, which appears to be a/the replacement plugin. Installing it, disabling Cycles Render Engine (and of course, enabling Radeon Prorender) seems to help. Being a bit of a novice to blender, comments are still wellcome. Anyway, hitting F12, although no intermediate ray traces are shown, yields a render in slightly over half the time it took in 3.5 using Cycles Render Engine, so it looks ok.